# The instance of entity type 'Profile' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1087}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4, Microsoft SQL Server 2019. I catch error

> The instance of entity type 'Profile' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the key value '{Id: 1087}' is already being
> tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
> instance with a given key value is attached.

My code

Entity

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace linkedin_mp.Models
{
    public partial class Profile
    {
        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public string LinkedinUrl { get; set; }
        public string ProfileIdNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
        public decimal? Version { get; set; }
        public bool? IsTarget { get; set; }
    }
}
```

dbcontext

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using linkedin_mp.Models;

namespace linkedin_mp.Data
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Profile> Profile { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=D1CMPS_VYDN;Database=linkedin;User Id=sa; Password=my_secret;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                    .HasColumnName("created")
                    .HasViewColumnName("created")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsTarget)
                    .HasColumnName("isTarget")
                    .HasViewColumnName("isTarget");

                entity.Property(e => e.LinkedinUrl)
                    .HasColumnName("linkedin_url")
                    .HasViewColumnName("linkedin_url")
                    .HasMaxLength(2048);

                entity.Property(e => e.Modified)
                    .HasColumnName("modified")
                    .HasViewColumnName("modified")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileIdNumber)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_id_number")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_id_number")
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                    .HasColumnName("version")
                    .HasViewColumnName("version")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileDetail>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(x => x.DetailId)
                    .HasName("PK__profile___38E9A224D0C5029F");

                entity.ToTable("profile_detail");

                entity.Property(e => e.DetailId)
                    .HasColumnName("detail_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("detail_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.Birthday)
                    .HasColumnName("birthday")
                    .HasViewColumnName("birthday")
                    .HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                    .HasColumnName("email")
                    .HasViewColumnName("email")
                    .HasMaxLength(512);

                entity.Property(e => e.ExperienceSetId)
                    .HasColumnName("experience_set_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("experience_set_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.FullAddress)
                    .HasColumnName("full_address")
                    .HasViewColumnName("full_address")
                    .HasMaxLength(2048);

                entity.Property(e => e.InstantMessageSetId)
                    .HasColumnName("instant_message_set_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("instant_message_set_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.InterestSetId)
                    .HasColumnName("interest_set_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("interest_set_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileAbout)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_about")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_about")
                    .HasMaxLength(2048);

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileAddress)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_address")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_address")
                    .HasMaxLength(1024);

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileHeadEducation)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_head_education")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_head_education")
                    .HasMaxLength(1024);

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileHeadJob)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_head_job")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_head_job")
                    .HasMaxLength(1024);

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileHeadline)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_headline")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_headline")
                    .HasMaxLength(1024);

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileId)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ProfileName)
                    .HasColumnName("profile_name")
                    .HasViewColumnName("profile_name")
                    .HasMaxLength(1024);

                entity.Property(e => e.SkillSetId)
                    .HasColumnName("skill_set_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("skill_set_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ToolTechSetId)
                    .HasColumnName("tool_tech_set_id")
                    .HasViewColumnName("tool_tech_set_id")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getprofile")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get2()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            using IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("nav__button-secondary")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("my_username");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("my_password" + Keys.Enter);
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var profilesList = from p in dbContext.Profile
                               where p.Id >= 1087 && p.Id <=1226 
                               select p;
            List<Profile> profiles = profilesList.ToList<Profile>();
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            int count = profiles.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < profilesList.Count(); i++)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(profiles[i].LinkedinUrl);
                Profile profile = new Profile();
                profile.Id = profiles[i].Id;
                IWebElement webElement1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words")));
                string profile_name = webElement1.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                profile.ProfileName = profile_name;

                // profile_headline
                IWebElement webElement2 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                string profile_headline = webElement2.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("profile_headline = " + profile_headline);
                profile.ProfileHeadline = profile_headline;

                // short_address
                IWebElement webElement3 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.t-16.t-black.t-normal.inline-block")));
                string short_address = webElement3.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("sort_address = " + short_address);
                profile.ProfileAddress = short_address;

                dbContext.Profile.Update(profile);
                dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Save to profile_detail success.");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

                // profile_address . đang sai
                // IWebElement webElement4 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                // Console.WriteLine("profile_address = " + webElement4.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());

                // full_address. chưa lấy được từ pop-up.
                // IWebElement webElement5 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id[starts-with(., 'ember')]/div/section[2]/div/a")));
                // Console.WriteLine(webElement5.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The instance of entity type 'Profile' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1087}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Update[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity)
   at linkedin_mp.Controllers.LinkedInController.Get2() in E:\github\xxx\linkedin_crawler\Controllers\LinkedInController.cs:line 279
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: Changes are already tracked in list "profiles". Creating new object "profile" in for loop causing this exception. Instead, try using objects in list "profiles" without creating new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reuse existing profile. Instead of :

```
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.Id = profiles[i].Id;
```

You can just assign `profiles[i]` to `profile`:

```
Profile profile = profiles[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a new (an another) Dbcontext for Adding action

```
ApplicationDbContext dbContext2 = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

more detail:

```cs
ApplicationDbContext dbContext2 = new ApplicationDbContext();

            for (int i = 0; i < profilesList.Count(); i++)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(profiles[i].LinkedinUrl);
                Profile profile = new Profile();

                profile.Id = profiles[i].Id;

                IWebElement webElement1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words")));
                string profile_name = webElement1.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("profile_name = " + profile_name);
                profile.ProfileName = profile_name;

                // profile_headline
                IWebElement webElement2 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                string profile_headline = webElement2.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("profile_headline = " + profile_headline);
                profile.ProfileHeadline = profile_headline;

                // short_address
                IWebElement webElement3 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.t-16.t-black.t-normal.inline-block")));
                string short_address = webElement3.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("sort_address = " + short_address);
                profile.ProfileAddress = short_address;

                dbContext2.Profile.Update(profile);
                dbContext2.SaveChangesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Save to profile_detail success.");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

                // profile_address . đang sai
                // IWebElement webElement4 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("h2.mt1")));
                // Console.WriteLine("profile_address = " + webElement4.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());

                // full_address. chưa lấy được từ pop-up.
                // IWebElement webElement5 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id[starts-with(., 'ember')]/div/section[2]/div/a")));
                // Console.WriteLine(webElement5.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Trim());
            }
            return list;
```